# Limiting Post-Map Results

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects that I am mapping and then return a component if it matches with the an id (`<AttachedComment />`). This setup works as expected with the code below, however, I would like to limit the post-map results to only the first three items. pre-map slicing isn't the right approach because it is limiting the array amount before the id matching. Is there a good method to slice the post-mapped array?

**Original array map:**

```
{ this.props.comments.map((comment, i) =>
                    <AttachedComment key={comment.recordCommentId} deleteCommentFunc={this.props.deleteCommentFunc} commentObj={comment} recordComponentId={this.props.recordId} userId={this.props.user} csrf={this.props.csrf}/>
                    )}
```

`AttachedComment`:

```
const AttachedComment = props => {
    if(props.commentObj.recordIdHash == props.recordComponentId){
        return (
            <Comment {...props.commentObj} deleteCommentFunc={props.deleteCommentFunc} key={props.commentObj.recordCommentId} currentUserId={props.userId} csrf={props.csrf}/>
            )
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First at the start of the render method filter out the comments you want and assign it to a new array. Next slice the result before map operation as shown below.

Note: don't need the if condition in `AttachedComment` component if you use below approach

```
render() {
    const filteredList = this.props.comments.filter((comment) => comment.recordIdHash === this.props.recordId);

    return (
        <div>
            {filteredList.slice(0, 3).map((comment, i) =>
                <AttachedComment key={comment.recordCommentId} deleteCommentFunc={this.props.deleteCommentFunc}
                                 commentObj={comment} recordComponentId={this.props.recordId}
                                 userId={this.props.user} csrf={this.props.csrf}/>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and answer. Since you say that your answer means that I shouldn't have to use `AttachedComment` is there a reason why you reference it in the `filteredList` map? Shouldn't it be the `Comment` component which was returned by the `AttachedComment`?

Comment: I assumed you have other logic within the `AttachedComment` component. If that is not the case, you don't need it. You can directly use `Comment` component.

Answer (score 0):

```
        let counter;
        const AttachedComment = props => {
        if(props.commentObj.recordIdHash == props.recordComponentId && counter < 4){
            return (
                 counter++
                <Comment {...props.commentObj} deleteCommentFunc={props.deleteCommentFunc} key={props.commentObj.recordCommentId} currentUserId={props.userId} csrf={props.csrf}/>

                )
        } else {
            return counter = 0;
        }
    }
```